# Display the posts only if both the categories exist

Tags: mysql, wordpress, customization

Display the posts only if both the categories exist.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

How we can get posts list both category exits only?

**bartags = 26,27**

```
if (isset($_POST['bartags']) && !empty($_POST['bartags'])):
        $tax_query[] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'bar_tag',
                'terms' => explode(',',$_POST['bartags']),
                'compare'=>'IN', // what's use here? 
            )
        );
    endif;
```

Comment: Can you explain your question clearly? 

Do you want to display the posts only if both the categories exist?

Comment: yes, we need only post both category exits only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['bartags']) && !empty($_POST['bartags'])):
        $tax_query[] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'bar_tag',
                'terms' => explode(',',$_POST['bartags']),
                'operator' => 'AND',
            )
        );
    endif;
```

This one fixed using **'operator' => 'AND'** which one not define on documents.